# How to insert a new column in between two column in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Reply Query for new column

```
alter table tb_Users add column Password nvarchar(250) after UserName
```

Comment: I don't think SQL Server allows you to do this.  You can define a view to put the columns in the order you desire when you use `select *`.

Answer (score 7):

**You can't. ALTER will not do it, because column order does not matter for storage or querying.**

If you really want to keep columns ordered you'll have to create a new table with the columns in that order and copy data. Or rename columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

Column order does not matters
just do this 
alter table tb_Users add column Password nvarchar(250)

and write the select query in the order you like

select UserName, Password from tb_Users